# UPPAAL error - java.io.IOException: Server Connection Lost

Tags: java, uppaal

I am learning about Formal Verification and I am supposed to use UPPAAL to which I am new. However, every time I start UPPAAL, I am greeted with the following error:

```
 java.io.IOException: Server Connection Lost
```

Is there any way to fix this error? I am using Ubuntu 12.04 as my OS on a 64 bit machine. I looked at the following posts, but since I am new to UPPAAL, I am unable to figure out the solution:

http://bugsy.grid.aau.dk/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=319

http://www.uppaal.com/index.php?sida=201&rubrik=95

http://forums.globalscape.com/Topic29575.aspx

https://groups.yahoo.com/neo/groups/uppaal/conversations/topics/2587

Any help would be appreciated in this regard!

Comment: The cause of this exception is the server somehow crashing. What version are you using? Could you try running bin-Linux/server in a terminal to see if there are more messages?

Comment: I suspect that 12.04 has too old system library (like libc) which prevents the server binary from running. Could you just upgrade to the next LTS release?

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue on windows 10 and i think @mariusm is right. I downloaded the later version of UPPAAL (i.e. 4.1.19) and issue is gone.