# Uppaal error : java.io.IOException: Server Connection lost

Tags: java, linux, uppaal

I am currently studying about formal verification and i have to use uppaal which is i am new. But if i run uppaal i got an error

> java.io.IOException: Server Connection lost

is there any way to fix it? I am using ubuntu 16.04 and openjdk8

I am looked on the following post

[UPPAAL error - java.io.IOException: Server Connection Lost](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37536058/uppaal-error-java-io-ioexception-server-connection-lost)

but i still unable to figure out the solution

Any help would be appreciated in this regard!

Comment: That message is a symptom of an engine server crash. Which version are you using? what exactly are you doing? perhaps something special with your model? Oracle JDK is recommended over OpenJDK, but it is not an issue here.

Answer (score 3):

Check if you are using UPPAAL version (i.e. 32bits, 64bits) that match your operating system.

I got this error and the problem was a mismatch between UPPAAL and OS architecture.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and solved it by installing a **32bit Virtualbox VM** (**Ubuntu 16.04.1, 32bit**) and **Java 6** from Oracle, see [here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-java-with-apt-get-on-ubuntu-16-04).

Inside the virtual machine, **UPPAAL 4.0.14** works and the server does not crash.